# How to have an observable return values one after another

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there an rxjs function / other way to do this (where  is a function that hopefully exists):

```
    let testOb$ = of(4).pipe(
      <???>(input => of(input + 2)),
      <???>(input => of(input - 3))
    )
    testOb$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))

    // logs 4, then 6, then 3
    // switchMap and mergeMap just returns 3
```

Note that the values should come one after another, and not complete all at once, then log the 3 values separately.

Use case:

I want to load some troublesome `data` consisting of an array of objects.

Each of the objects has a single value that is too large, and if loaded all together, causes significant lag. But so long as one is loaded first, there's no UI lag.

So I would like to:

```
data$ = this._store.dispatch(fetchInitial())
    .pipe(
        <???>(data => fillInitial(data))
        <???>(data => fillRemainder(data))
    )
data$.subscribe(data => renderInput(data))
```

Is this a valid approach?

If not, what is considered best practice for this kind of use case with rxjs?

Comment: What is this `<???>` ?

Comment: Do you want the operator? It's `mergeMap` or `switchMap` depending on your scenario.

Comment: Edited to reflect the questions. I don't think either `mergeMap` or `switchMap` work. Subscribing only leaves me with the value contained in the last Observable of the pipe

Comment: "Each of the objects has a single value that is too large...But so long as one is loaded first, there's no UI lag." - One object, or one value? Are you looking to pull out one object, process it, and then process all of the other objects afterward?

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, didn't read carefully enough. Thanks

Comment: @Zircon
the incoming data would look like
`
[{key0: value0, key1: value1 ...}]
`
except `key9`'s value will be about 3MB

so when it starts, i would like it to read {key9: null}, and update it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output can be achieved like this:

```
let testOb$ = of(4).pipe(
  mergeMap(input => from([input, input + 2])),
  mergeMap(input => from([input, input - 3])),
  filter((val, index) => index != 1)
);
testOb$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

It looks weird because your desired output doesn't really follow a simple rule. But it works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cmxgan?devtoolsheight=60

Now, for your second example, we would do something like this to avoid the delay:

```
data$ = this._store.dispatch(fetchInitial())
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(data => fillInitial(data).pipe(startWith(data)))
    mergeMap(data => fillRemainder(data).pipe(startWith(data))),
    filter((val, index) => index != 1)
)
```

Comment: Hey, that does work. I need to update the question then.


If I add a `delay` between each `mergeMap`, an issue arises: `testOb$` spits out `4, 6, 3` all at once, instead of one at a time with some delay in between.


If I replace `delay` with API calls, then there would be no point. There would be separate calls, but no intermediate values given so that the UI can start rendering a bit earlier

Comment: Well, not really, your calls are not a delay like the operator but rather an observable that is subscribed to. Please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 separate streams and merge when you need.

```
   let testOb$ = of(4).pipe(share());

   const six$ = testOb$.pipe(mergeMap(input => of(input + 2)));
   const three$ = testOb$.pipe(mergeMap((input => of(input - 3)));

   merge(testOb$, six$, three$).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```